# How do I convert this VB.NET code to C#?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, vb.net-to-c#

```
Dim MaxItemID As Integer
Dim objCMD As New SqlCommand(StrSql, objConn)  
MaxItemID = IIf(IsDBNull(objCMD.ExecuteScalar()), 0, objCMD.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
```

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Seriously - there are **tons** of free, web-based C#-VB.NET convertors - just Google or Bing for them! [This is just one of the many many many options.....](http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/CSharp-To-Vb.aspx)

Comment: google vb to c#.hit the first link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (and avoid executing the SQL twice):

```
var objCMD = new SqlCommand(StrSql, objConn);
var sqlRes = objCMD.ExecuteScalar();
int maxItemID = 1 + (Convert.IsDBNull(sqlRes) ? 0 : (int)sqlRes);
```

Note VB will convert the `object` return of `ExecuteScalar` to an `int` implicitly, but C# will not.

Comment: Where are you getting "Converter.IsDBNull" from?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas My imagination, should be [`Convert.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) of course (will correct).

Comment: It's just weird since I saw it in another answer also.  I thought maybe it was some new class in .NET 4.5.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas That's because I was too lazy to check the class name when answering (I knew the method name... and that other answer had it...). I should know better, always have to correct DbNUll handling (while wishing `Nullable<T>` could be retro-fitted into ADO.NET).

Answer (score 1):

```
int MaxItemID = 0;
using(SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(StrSql, objConn))
{
    MaxItemID = (Converter.IsDBNull(objCMD.ExecuteScalar()) ? 0 : objCMD.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Use `Converter.IsDBNull` instead.

Comment: There is no Converter.IsDBNull.  Use System.Convert.IsDBNull.

Answer (score 0):

```
int MaxItemID;
SqlCommand objCMD =new SqlCommand (StrSql, objConn);
MaxItemID = IsDBNull(objCMD.ExecuteScalar()? 0: objCMD.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
```

Comment: There is no global "IsDBNull" in C#.  User System.Convert.IsDBNull.